# Processing input for a label actor

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a `Label` actor on a `Stage` and I can't, for the life of me, get input, i.e. `touchDown` and `touchUp` events fired.

In my `show()` method I have this too:
`Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(mainMenuStage);`

Initialise the `Label` and set its position and the bounds, then I add an `EventListener` to the `Label` like so:

```
myLabel.addListener(new InputListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            super.touchDown(event, x, y, pointer, button);
            System.out.println("touchdown");
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            super.touchUp(event, x, y, pointer, button);
            System.out.println("touchup");
        }
    });
```

Once the `Label` is all set-up I add it to the `Stage`

But nothing is printed in the `LogCat`/`Console`, when I tap on `myLabel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am so stupid!! -.-

I was calling `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(mainMenuStage);` before I had even intialised my `mainMenuStage`. Funny that I never got a `NullReferenceException` though.

Anyway, got it working, finally =]]